# check POST request with Fiddler

Tags: http-post, fiddler

How can I use Fiddler to check the response from a web server. I could easily check the GET method by pasting the url to the field in Request Builder and get the response back in xml/json. There is an option POST, however I don't know how can I pass the parameters to the POST.

For example:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
request.Method = "POST";

string postData = "accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE";
postData += "&Email=yourusername@gmail.com";
postData += "&Passwd=yourpassword";
postData += "&service=finance";
postData += "&source=test-test-.01";
```

How can I pass my Data into this POST method in Fiddler to get the response?

Comment: Is this a question about WP7 or about Fiddler? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: it's really about Fiddler :P but I use c# code to explain my parameters. :P

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The *simplest* way to do this is to have Fiddler capture an instance of this request and drag/drop that session onto the Request builder.

But generating a post yourself isn't hard. Set the RequestBuilder's method to POST, add a header:

`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

And put in the Request Body the text of the post:

`accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&Email=yourusername@gmail.com&Passwd=yourpassword&service=finance&source=test-test-.01`

Comment: A big thumbs up for this, despite it being nearly nine years ago it was posted. It's amazing that it's taken me so long to find such a simple solution in adding this Content-Type, because I couldn't find that advice anywhere else. I'm puzzled that Fiddler, now on Version 5, doesn't prompt or suggest this.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Composer with Http Post, URL, Header and Body]

[image: And Result console.log at Server with Json]

Step 1: Composer with Http Post, URL, Header and Body
Step 2: And Result console.log at Server with Json