# when we could send parameters by post why Http introduced put and patch?

Tags: rest, http

I am trying to send parameters to my rest controller using postman and i see no difference when i use post, put or patch. Why HTTP introduced these methods if they are just same ?

Comment: they aren't "just the same". Any competent introduction to HTTP should explain their differences.

Comment: we can update a resource using post method then what is the main reason to introduce put and patch ? @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Possible Duplicate - [What is the difference between PUT, POST and PATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31089221/15498)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between PUT, POST and PATCH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089221/what-is-the-difference-between-put-post-and-patch)