# Uncaught Exception : class org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException : Request method 'PUT' not supported

Tags: spring-boot

I created `PatchMapping` in Spring boot
When I want to modified and I use method Put it

> ====== error : Uncaught Exception : class org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException :
>   Request method 'PUT' not supported ==================

If I use Method `patch` it working normal.

Comment: Show actual code you are using

Comment: in restcontroller i have Patchmapping ,not have putMapping so when i use put from client side it error 500 "internal server error" . so i want to return to user error 400 "put method not have."

Comment: I believe we understand that you have an issue, but we can only fix your code if we see your code, otherwise it is just a wild guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke a service by doing PUT verb, you need to add spring-boot annotation:

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/yourURL", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
```

PATCH is not the same as PUT.  You can find more info on:

[What is the difference between PUT, POST and PATCH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089221/what-is-the-difference-between-put-post-and-patch?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Exception tells us `Request method 'PUT' not supported`. Not related with `POST` or `PATCH`.

Comment: OK.  If you need to do an update, you need to declare service as method=RequestMethod.PUT, instead of POST.  Annotation @RequestBody will be necessary too on the input parameter that contains the values to update.

Comment: Thank you but when i use patch working normal but i want to handle when use method put , now error {
    "status": 500,
    "message": "internal server error"
}

Comment: i want handle it and return 400 . how to catch exception method in restcontroller in spring

Comment: You  need one class that implements ErrorController.  @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<RestInvalidParameter> processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        RestInvalidParameter error = new RestInvalidParameter(ex);
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Error: {0}", error);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

Comment: @NachoSoriano, Then update your answer for fellow users.

Comment: sorry i'm not clear about that can you give me simple and another reference . thank you for help

Comment: @SeanMengKong All these comments are symptomatic of the question being poorly asked. Fix the question please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the exception, create one class that implements ErrorController:

```
@Controller
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestErrorHandler implements ErrorController {

@ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<RestInvalidParameter> processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nacho It is not necessary to implements  `ErrorController` for the class `RestErrorHandler`.

Comment: @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
 public void  methodNotAllowed(Exception ex) throws ResourceNotFoundException, URISyntaxException, ResourceViolationException,ResourceNotFoundException ,ResourceNotFoundException{
      throw ex;
    }

Comment: please solve ResourceNotFoundException, URISyntaxException, ResourceViolationException,ResourceNotFoundException ,ResourceNotFoundException that is class extend from exception but i don't know which class have error when i use exception .

Comment: @Nacho any idea please

Comment: You can set collection to annotation @ExceptionHandler({ResourceNotFoundException.class, URISyntaxException.class, ResourceViolationException.class}, for example, and inside the method, use "instanceof" in order to throw distinct HttpStatus for each exception.

Comment: @SeanMengKong, could you confirm if my last comment solves your problem?

Comment: @NachoSoriano Thank so much for your help sir, but another one i want handle only HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException and another exception i want to ignore without handler. what should i do ? if have any comment please advice thank you.