# JSON server - post data into specific object in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, fetch, react-hooks

I'm practicing fetch api and have problem with posting data... in first step I post to 'http://localhost:3003/users' and it works fine -> code:

```
(async () => {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3003/users', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({ name, password }),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        });
```

but in another component (second step) I have this code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const resp = await fetch(`http://localhost:3003/users/${userID}`, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({ tasks: [1, 2, 3] }),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        }).then(res => console.log(res));
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    })();
  }, [userID]);
```

and after logging to the console, got this:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:3003/users/0", redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:3003/users/0"
```

But when I go to http://localhost:3003/users/0, I can see the user so it seems that url works... Of course when I delete ${userID} it works, but array is added as the last object, not to this specific user... What's more - http://localhost:3003/users/${userID} works with GET method.

The question is - how to post data to single object in array in JSON server??

db.json:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Ola",
      "password": "12345"
    },
    {
      "name": "newuser",
      "password": "newuser",
      "id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

form submission checks if there is a user with this name; if not, post new user

Comment: What kind of webserver are you using?

Comment: i'm using json-server

Comment: can you post your db.json file

Comment: yes - i've added above

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVED

I used wrong method - POST instead of PATCH

Answer (score 0):

So when you are posting something, in your case you are posting it to the users array

so it should be try in this way

```
fetch(`http://localhost:3003/users`)
```

and in your body you need to pass the id

```
{ id:`${userId}` tasks: [1, 2, 3] }
```

Update these things and check.

OR

**Update**

As it is adding a new property to the user object need to use Patch instead of Post

You can read more on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089221/what-is-the-difference-between-put-post-and-patch)

Comment: it didn't work - now i have 500 and Internal Server Error

Comment: I've got it - I used wrong method in fetch request (POST instead of PATCH). Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: I have updated it kindly check and vote so for the other people it will be helpful